# Login Screen Crashes and enter without password in 14.04LTS?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, login, windows-8, auto-login

I am using ubuntu14.04LTS in dual boot mode with window8.1.

I have set the password for both, and in ubuntu whenever prompt for password it crashes. It wont allow me to put even the mouse_pointer into the password prompt window. It simply crash into my ubuntu_OS.

Please anyone know the reason and fix?

[Check the Video here](https://youtu.be/WA1fRvwHkW0)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching to other windows manager? For example, `lightdm, gdm, kdm, xdm`. You can do that by simply running `sudo apt-get install kdm`, then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm`, and choose that one or install any other windows manager and do the same thing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23248/discussion-on-answer-by-pavol-polacko-login-screen-crashes-and-enter-without-pas).

Comment: The problem persist